# R tmap: Adjust line height in two-line legend title

Tags: r, legend, tmap

Could you please help me with this problem?  I want to put a legend title on two lines, and control legend placement in a figure that meets font size and figure size requirements. I am mapping a count variable to political units.  Here, hopefully, is a reproducible example, using:

Mac OS 10.14.6; RStudio vers. 2021.09.0, R vers. 4.1.2, tmap vers. 3.3-2

I tried the obvious within tm_fill(). I added a newline to the title text, but the exaggerated line height (space) between the lines of the title is distracting:

```
library(sf)
library(tmap)
library(tidyverse)
library(RColorBrewer)
set.seed(12345)
shp <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package ="sf")) %>% 
  st_transform(shape, crs = 4326) %>%
  mutate(myvar = sample(1:50,100,replace=TRUE)) %>%
  select(myvar)

mymap <- tm_shape(shp) +
   tm_fill(col= "myvar",
            style = "fixed",
            breaks = c(1,10,20,30,40,50), 
            palette = "YlOrRd",
            title = "Number of\nPrograms")+
   tm_layout(legend.position=c("right","top"),inner.margins = c(rep(0.02,3),0.2))

tmap_save(mymap,filename= "NC1.png", width = 180, units="mm")
```

[image: map 1]

Several responses to similar questions regarding ggplot2 suggested using atop() and some additional functions, [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40577023/r-ggplot-annotated-with-atop-using-three-values-and-bgroup).

```
mymap2 <- tm_shape(shp) +
   tm_fill(col= "myvar",
            style = "fixed",
            breaks = c(1,10,20,30,40,50), 
            palette = "YlOrRd",
            title = expression(atop(textstyle(" \n"),
                                  atop(textstyle("Number of"),
                                       atop(textstyle("Programs")))))) +
   tm_layout(legend.position=c("right","bottom"),legend.title.size = 1.5,inner.margins = c(rep(0.02,3),0.2))

tmap_save(mymap2,filename= "NC2.png", width = 80,units="mm")
```

[image: map 2]

The legend title line height is improved in the RStudio plot window, but not in .png or .pdf output.  The new legend placement responds minimally to 'legend.position=' in tm_layout().  As noted in another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47505738/manipulating-the-font-of-a-legend-title-with-tmap) 'legend.title.size=' only moves the title higher above the legend, but does *not* change the title font size.

I also get these warning messages when saving the file:

```
Warning messages:
1: In grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  :
  font metrics unknown for character 0xa
2: In grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  :
  font metrics unknown for character 0xa
3: In grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  :
  font metrics unknown for character 0xa
4: In grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  :
  font metrics unknown for character 0xa
```

Could you please help me format this legend, correcting the line height and font size in the legend title, and placing the legend "right","top" in the map area?

Comment: Try saving to an SVG and editing in Inkscape or other vector editor?